# Chart.js - remove zeros and step numbers in Y axis

Tags: chart.js

The Chart.js code I have is:

```js
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: tempDate.reverse(),
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [2000,2001,2002,2003],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false,
                    display: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

and the result looks like this:
[image]

I am trying to remove the **2001.5** and **2002.5** from the y axis and also the 0 behind other values in y axis.

Basically I am trying to print exactly the data I am passing to it which is `[2000,2001,2002,2003]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [stepSize](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#step-size) in your options

```
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                stepSize: 1,
                beginAtZero: false,
                display: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```